# Selenium - EventFiringWebDriver beforeFindBy and afterFindBy methods fires same event multiple times

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdrivereventlistener

I have implemented WebDriverEventListener in my project to log events. I am facing an issue that same events are fired multiple times for **beforeFindBy** and **afterFindBy** methods in WebDriverEventListener Interface though I registered eventListener only once. Not sure what went wrong. My code goes as follows. Please help on this.

**PageClass**

```
package pageobjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class TestHome {

    WebDriverWait wait;
    WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(className = "noo-search")
    public WebElement lnkSearch;

    public TestHome(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void clickSearchIcon() {
        clickElement(lnkSearch);
    }

    public void waitForElementToBeClickable(WebElement element) {
        try {
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            throw new TimeoutException("Element not clickable within the given time..");
        }
    }

    public void clickElement(WebElement element) {
        waitForElementToBeClickable(element);
        element.click();
    }
}
```

**Listener**

```
package listeners;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.WebDriverEventListener;

public class EventHandler implements WebDriverEventListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeAlertAccept(WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterAlertAccept(WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterAlertDismiss(WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeAlertDismiss(WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeNavigateTo(String s, WebDriver webDriver) {
        System.out.println("Before Navigate to " + s);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterNavigateTo(String s, WebDriver webDriver) {
        System.out.println("After Navigate to " + s);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeNavigateBack(WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterNavigateBack(WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeNavigateForward(WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterNavigateForward(WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeNavigateRefresh(WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterNavigateRefresh(WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeFindBy(By by, WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver) {
        System.out.println("Before finding element " + by);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterFindBy(By by, WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver) {
        System.out.println("After finding element " + by);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeClickOn(WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterClickOn(WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeChangeValueOf(WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver, CharSequence[] charSequences) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterChangeValueOf(WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver, CharSequence[] charSequences) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeScript(String s, WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterScript(String s, WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeSwitchToWindow(String s, WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterSwitchToWindow(String s, WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onException(Throwable throwable, WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public <X> void beforeGetScreenshotAs(OutputType<X> outputType) {

    }

    @Override
    public <X> void afterGetScreenshotAs(OutputType<X> outputType, X x) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeGetText(WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterGetText(WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver, String s) {

    }
}
```

**TestClass**

```
import listeners.EventHandler;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver;
import pageobjects.TestHome;

public class TestClass {

    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        EventFiringWebDriver eDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
        EventHandler listener = new EventHandler();
        eDriver.register(listener);

        eDriver.get("https://shop.demoqa.com");
        TestHome home = new TestHome(eDriver);
        home.clickSearchIcon();

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab) on port 47488
Only local connections are allowed.
Dec 30, 2019 11:56:46 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Before Navigate to https://shop.demoqa.com
After Navigate to https://shop.demoqa.com
Before finding element By.className: noo-search
After finding element By.className: noo-search
Before finding element By.className: noo-search
After finding element By.className: noo-search
Before finding element By.className: noo-search
After finding element By.className: noo-search

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `PageClass`, you have the following which uses `WebDriverWait.until`:

```
    public void waitForElementToBeClickable(WebElement element) {
        try {
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            throw new TimeoutException("Element not clickable within the given time..");
        }
    }
```

`WebDriverWait.until` works by executing the `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` until it returns true, or the timeout duration is reached. It takes a bit of time for your element to actually appear, and the `WebDriverWait.until` is executing a few times before finally returning true.

From the [docs](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/AbstractWebDriverEventListener.html), we can see that your `findBeforeBy` and `findAfterBy` functions are indeed being called multiple times by the `WebDriverWait.until` function. For instance, the `findAfterBy` function's description points to this:

> Called after WebDriver.findElement(...), or WebDriver.findElements(...), or WebElement.findElement(...), or WebElement.findElements(...).

Comment: I suspect the same but if I add some hard wait time(say 10 seconds) before `waitForElementToBeClickable` line assuming that the element will become clickable by that time. Even after that also I am getting multiple fire events for the same action. Does it mean that `findElement()` may poll the DOM multiple times even when the element is clickable? If yes, that solves my query.

Comment: @MehavarnanMurugan it's likely that's what's happening. You could also put in a non-present element and see if the `findBeforeBy` is called multiple times. At the very least, this would verify that the function is being called multiple times from within the `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable`. Hence, it would mean that `findElemen` is doing something "under the hood" that is causing the `findAfterBy` and `findBeforeBy` to be called